# How to send get request in ITMS url in PHP?

Tags: php, ios, plist

I have the following code which is not working. Means ITMS service dont call the URL with get request.

```
header('Location: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mysite.com/plistReader.php?id=123');
```

If i remove `id=123` its start working. But i need to send this as to keep id dynamic. In Session also i am unable to pass. Please help.

Comment: Try escaping the '?', and '=' with %3F, and %3D respectively: url=http://www.mysite.com/plistReader.php%3Fid%3D123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to URL-encode that question mark as `%3F`, as it is a reserved character.  As @wroniasty pointed out, you also need to encode the `=` as `%3D`.

```
header('Location: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mysite.com/plistReader.php%3Fid%3D123');
```

See also:  http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: @Varun, Good catch.  Typo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Never escape URL characters by hand. Let PHP 5's functions - `urlencode()` and `http_build_query()` - do the hard work for you. This avoids issues where some of your GET parameter name/value pairs may have sensitive characters that need to be transmitted e.g.

```
<?php
    $base_url = "http://www.example.com/plistReader.php";
    $data = Array("id" => 123, "dangerous" => ":?&= are some sensitive chars");

    $itms_url = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" . urlencode($base_url . "?" . http_build_query($data));
    header('Location: ' . $itms_url);
?>
```